# Windows Application not re-establishing SQL Server database connection Once it is lost

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

C# Windows application is often losing database connection due to bad network, so that users losing their data changes.

Once the SQL Sever connection is lost, how to reconnect, even not prompting to user? I would like to fix this issue globally.

Please suggest..

Comment: 1) Fix the network. 2) Don't rely on a constantly open connection in your application.

Comment: well. applications are installed in client machines, database is in central location. not all the clients complaining this, but few clients, looking for solution to fix

Comment: Are you opening/closing the connection before/after each database operation? As @Rhumborl suggested, do not keep the connection open all the time.